# C# Array Initialization

Tags: c#, initialization

As someone with a background in C, C++ and assembly language, one thing that has always bothered me about C# is that I cannot do something like this:

```
struct OperatorType
{
    string Operator;
    TokenType Type;
}

protected static OperatorType[] Operators = {
    { "{", TokenType.OpenBrace }
};
```

I'd like to declare this so that it doesn't require allocation and initialization at run time but C# won't allow it.

Yes, I understand I can initialize with `new OperatoryType() { Operator = "{", Type = TokenType.OpenBrace }`. But doesn't that involve a run-time allocation and initialization of memory? I know it's not that much overhead but I don't understand why it is necessary here.

Can anyone explain why this bit of additional overhead is required by C#, or possibly a way to do this without the run-time allocation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with having static data simply mapped from a binary file is that it requires the format of all the data to be frozen at compile time. Since the runtime determines the layout of structures (including strings and arrays), the compiler can't know what the layout will be. Even if the compiler emitted the layout of the current runtime, it could be broken by future runtimes. This means that only structs with explicit layout that were defined in that assembly could be statically mapped from a file, which is quite frankly not too useful.

The C# Language Specification 4.0, section 7.6.10.4 says:

> Except in an unsafe context (§18.1), the layout of arrays is unspecified.

In 18.5.8:

> The order in which members are packed into a struct is unspecified.

The layout of `string` actually changed between .NET 3.5 and 4.0 (they removed a field); it went from

```
[NonSerialized]
private int m_arrayLength;
[NonSerialized]
private char m_firstChar;
[NonSerialized]
private int m_stringLength;
```

to

```
[NonSerialized, ForceTokenStabilization]
private char m_firstChar;
[NonSerialized]
private int m_stringLength;
```

This isn't a problem in C or C++ because the compiler determines the layout of structs. Of course this also means that you have to recompile everything that uses a struct/class in order to change its layout.

Comment: Do you know of any reference that documents that "the runtime determines the layout of structures (including strings and arrays)"? Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan: I've the C# spec where it says that the layout is unspecified. This means that it must be up to the runtime, otherwise you wouldn't be able to run code compiled by one compiler on a framework compiled with a different one.

Comment: @Jonathan: I've edited my answer to show how the definition of `string` changed in version 4.0 of the runtime.

Answer (score 9):

Allocations, whether in C# or C++, always require allocation at runtime.  It's more a matter of *when* the allocations occur.

If you allocate in a static constructor in C#, you'll allocate sometime before the first usage of the type.  That should be safe, and not really have any extra overhead when compared to your C++ version.

Also, one thing to realize - runtime allocations in C# tend to be much cheaper than C++.  This is one huge advantage of the garbage collector.  It's very likely this is a classic case of premature optimization.  I would recommend not worrying about this unless you've found a real, measured performance issue.

Comment: I know allocations require allocations at run time. What I don't understand is why an allocation is necessary here. In C or C++, I can simply declare the structure in memory, which is loaded directly from the EXE image. No allocation is required. I understand the prevailing mentality is that C# developers shouldn't worry too much about optimizing, which explains why my C# apps can be so much slower than my C++ apps. That's fine if other people don't care but I'm personally very interested in why this isn't supported.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: C++ developers shouldn't worry too much about optimizing either. Both sets of programmers (C++ and C#) should worry exactly the right amount, and they probably have more in common on this issue than you might think.

Comment: @Jonathan: "Loading from EXE image" is an allocation.  The allocation in C# is actually far faster than in C++ - it's just shifting the allocation time (when you use a static constructor) from application startup to an indeterminant time prior to the first usage.  The allocation, however, will likely be much faster in C# than the initial allocation time in your C++ application.

Comment: @Jason: I'm sorry if I don't seem impressed but I've been programming more than long enough to know when I should worry about optimizations.

Comment: @Reed: That doesn't make sense to me. When the EXE loader loads an EXE into memory, static data in C++ is simply copied as part of that data. There is no call to `malloc()` or any other code to allocate individual static variables. It's loaded into memory before the program executes. How is this a run-time allocation? And how could C# possibly run memory allocation and initialization code for individual variables in less time?

Comment: @Jonathan: The OS is doing the runtime allocation in C#, in order to allocate memory for copying the data.  In C#, the OS call is the same, but this is not pre-loaded (unless it happens to be in one of the first types used by the program), so the allocation happens later.  However, in C#, most allocations don't require a malloc, as the GC tends to manage a pool of memory that's always available, so an allocation is fast - it's typically just a pointer movement and clear operation instead of an OS request for memory.

Comment: @Reed: Did you mean the OS is doing the allocation in C++? In C++, there is no allocation for individual static variables. It just allocates a larger block of memory for the data image. There is generally no overhead at all for allocating a slightly larger block of memory. I'm not sure what C# does but my use of `new` makes me think an allocation routine is being called for each static variable. How could that possibly be faster than no overhead at all?

Comment: @Jonathan: .NET applications can perform well or poorly, and C++ applications can perform well or poorly. @Reed answers the meat of the question correctly here, as there will be a runtime allocation no matter what so the syntax you seek would only be syntactic sugar, not a meaningful increase in performance. For the *literal* answer to the question, see @Danny Chen's answer.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: I don't know how I can be any more clear that, in fact, there is *no* per-static-variable allocation in the case of C++. If you can counter this, please do. Otherwise, I can only assume you haven't read the comments you are responding to. And if there is no per-static-variable allocation, then Reed's response clearly does not address the meat of the question.

Comment: @Jonathan: I didn't say there was; the question is about C#, not C++. Reed's response addresses the meat of the question because, again, *this is about C#*. The reason this doesn't exist in C# is because *all* "allocations" (and by allocation, I'm including what you might refer to as loading data from the binary) occur at runtime, so the syntax you seek would be of little value. If you want to ask why you cannot persist a binary representation of structures in the image and just essentially `memcpy` them into use, then see @Gabe's answer.

Comment: @Adam Robinson: If your comment "there will be a runtime allocation no matter what" was specific to C#, then I misunderstood. I wasn't able to tell from the context and you seemed to be supporting Reed's comments, which said just that. Note that I have already marked @Gabe's reply as the answer as, for me, he most closely answers the meat of the question.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: I did not claim that you did not know when to worry about optimizations, and I'm sorry if something in my comment can be read that way. You made the statement that "C# developers shouldn't worry too much about optimizing" and I am merely claiming that statement is misguided. You statements here and elsewhere that performance is not a concern for .NET developers is patently false.

Comment: @Jason: I never said C# developers shouldn't worry too much about optimizing. In fact, I'm saying just the opposite. I'm also saying I get a lot of crap from many .NET developers every time I post here about making my C# apps more efficient. I'm sorry if that's getting to be a sensitive spot for me, but in fact I've found that many C# developers don't worry too much about performance, and there are even examples of this within Microsoft.

Comment: @Jonathan: I wasn't suggesting that C# developers shouldn't worry about optimizing, either - and I don't want you to get that idea.  I spend a LOT of time optimizing C# code, on a very regular basis.  I was suggesting that C# developers (like all developers) should focus on optimizing *the right thing* - and, IMO, worrying about a very minor allocation like this is probably not the most efficient usage of optimization resources.  I do think there is a common flaw when people come to C# from a C/C++/Assembly background, however - the perf. characteristics of C# are dramatically different ...

Comment: ... C++ and other languages.  Many common C++ optimizations will actually cause C# code to run less efficiently.  The focus on what should be optimized, as well as the opportunity to optimize at a different level due to better tooling, really changes how we should all approach this type of problem, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a non default constructor to get a slightly more efficient version than using the object initializer syntax. There isn't really a runtime allocation other than the actual Operators array, the constructor will just get called for each location in that array

```
enum TokenType { OpenBrace, T2 };

struct OperatorType
{
    string Operator;
    TokenType Type;

    public OperatorType(string op, TokenType type)
    {
        Operator = op;
        Type = type;
    }
}

static OperatorType[] Operators = {
    new OperatorType( "{", TokenType.OpenBrace )
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure if I understand your second sentence. To me, the use of `new` for each item in the array indicates that there must be a run-time allocation for each item in the array. Of course, I'm open to being wrong if someone can show me otherwise. But isn't that what `new` does?

Comment: For a class new would result in an object being created in the heap, but for structs(a value type) there is no new object allocation. It just gets created on the stack for variables defined in a method or in the memory of the object it exists in as in the case of it being in an array.

Comment: @BrandonAGr: Interesting. According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx), "The new operator is also used to invoke the default constructor for value types." Of course, having to call an initializer is still something I sometimes wish I could avoid. But perhaps `new` does not allocate memory in this case. I'm seem to be having trouble finding information on exactly this point.

Comment: In the above code there is an implicit new OperatorType[1] that the compiler sticks in which is the only actual memory allocation performed to create the static Operators array. There are lots of tutorials out there on [Reference types vs Value types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) in C#

Comment: +1 For providing a little more information about what is happening under the covers, and for the interesting link. (I really have read a bit about this but the articles I found did not address the specific issue being raised here.)

Comment: @BrandonAGr, @Jonathan: it is not entirely true that there is no allocation of new storage when calling a constructor of a value type. The fact that an instance of a value type does not "own" its own storage (because there is no object identity to do the owning!) is not actually relevant; the relevant question is *whether or not the mutation of the storage by the constructor is visible to other code*. That determines whether (stack) storage is allocated or not. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/11/debunking-another-myth-about-value-types.aspx for additional details.

Comment: @Eric, After running through your examples and looking [at the IL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.newobj(v=VS.100).aspx) I might have to disagree on semantics, the allocation of new storage when calling a constructor of a value type is happening on the evaluation stack, which we really dont care about in terms of storage allocations. You make a good point in your article though, that modifications to the variable you are assigning to don't happen until the constructor successfully returns, there is a newobj then either a stobj or stloc call.

Comment: Allocations are allocations; what difference does it make if the allocation is the movement of ESP or the movement of the top of the GC heap? Are you concerned about collection pressure?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to your question: by design. And I believe the syntax in your question is theoretically possible to implement. But as Eric Lippert often answers those questions like "why can't I ... in C#":

> because no one ever designed,
>   specified, implemented, tested,
>   documented and shipped that feature.
>   All six of those things are necessary
>   to make a feature happen.

Comment: I guess so. And that's probably part of the reason I can usually tell a large application was written using .NET application because it takes forever to load. It sometimes seems performance no longer matters and if I raise the issue, I get the usual chorus of "don't optimize prematurely". I guess I thought there might actually be some logic behind the decision not to support this but perhaps I was being too optimistic.

Comment: @Jonathan: If a program is taking a long time to load, you can be almost certain that it's not because it's initializing static data!

Comment: @Gabe: I assumed the main reason is because of the huge libraries being loaded. However, my point stands that performance doesn't really seem to be a concern to .NET developers in general.

Comment: @Jonathan: Erm, really? Talk about a sweeping generalization. People who quote Knuth in this way (and they come from all software sectors, not just .NET) and are not concerned about performance, don't understand what the words "don't optimize prematurely" really mean.

Comment: @Gabe: I assure you that a great many startup performance problems are caused by initializing static data. I spent many months analyzing the startup performance problems of VSTO and it was in large part due to static initializer performance.

Comment: @Jonathan: I assure you that many .NET developers care deeply about performance. If you are having a problem with startup time performance then I suggest that you use a profiling tool in order to determine what is the actual cause; there are many possibilities other than simply lots of page faults to load the code. Jit time comes immediately to mind. Could be static initializers. Could be security checks. Could be any number of things. Get a profiler and find out.

Comment: @Robert and @Eric: I used the term *in general* for a reason. I'm well aware that some .NET developers care about performance, starting with myself. However, it seems that whenever I raise the issue, I get a lot of heat from .NET developers who seem to think performance is a non issue. Eric: I said I can tell when a large application was written in .NET. If I was writing the application myself, then obviously I know automatically which tools were used to write it.

Comment: @Jonathan: Ask the same question of your typical Java developers and I predict you get the same relative response from them.  Some of them have taken Knuth's quote to mean that they don't have to worry about performance, and so they don't.  But that doesn't mean that performance is not important, and it certainly doesn't mean that .NET developers (or Java developers, for that matter) as a whole do not care about performance.

Comment: @Robert: I'm not interested in an argument about exactly how many people care vs. how many do not care about performance in .NET. I can only repeat that whenever I raise performance-related issues it seems I always get a lot of heat for worrying about such thing. Thus the reason for my comment.

Comment: @Jonathan: I am merely pointing out that the people telling you this are not representative of .NET developers as a whole.  I daresay they are probably the wrong people with whom to be discussing issues like this.  They are, however, giving you sensible advice if they are telling you to use a profiler.  Most of us are maddeningly bad at guessing where the performance bottlenecks actually are.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to initialize at runtime, then do the creation of it in the static constructor.  So it won't get created until you call the class.Operators for the first time.

Comment: Yes, this is what I often end up doing. But I still don't get why this is necessary.

Comment: You should ask your question on the MSDN forums if you want an answer about why the language developers did something a certain way.